# Sql inner join not exist subquery error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL>   SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,
  2    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
  3    EVENT.EVENTLOCATION
  4    WHERE NOT EXISTS
  5    (SELECT * FROM EVENT.EVENTLOCATION AND EVENTLOCATION ="LONDON 02")
  6    FROM CUSTOMER
  7    INNER JOIN BOOKING
  8    ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
  9    INNER JOIN EVENT
 10    ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
 11    INNER JOIN CONCERTS
 12    ON CONCERTS.CONCERTID=EVENT.CONCERTID;
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I am getting a error on line 4 when trying to find customers who have not attended an event held in London using a inner join. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: `WHERE` comes after `FROM`.

Comment: SQL>   SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,
  2    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
  3    EVENT.EVENTLOCATION
  4    FROM CUSTOMER
  5    WHERE NOT EXISTS
  6    (SELECT * FROM EVENT WHERE EVENTLOCATION ="LONDON 02")
  7    INNER JOIN BOOKING
  8    ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
  9    INNER JOIN EVENT
 10    ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
 11    INNER JOIN CONCERTS
 12    ON CONCERTS.CONCERTID=EVENT.CONCERTID;
  INNER JOIN BOOKING
  *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: im getting an SQL command not properly ended error
?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are putting the exists statements in the select list where it should have been in the WHERE condition. I changed it as below

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
    EVENT.EVENTLOCATION
FROM CUSTOMER
    INNER JOIN BOOKING
        ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
    INNER JOIN EVENT
        ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
    INNER JOIN CONCERTS
        ON CONCERTS.CONCERTID=EVENT.CONCERTID;
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM EVENT.EVENTLOCATION WHERE EVENTLOCATION ='LONDON 02'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, it is better to put your "WHERE" clause after all joins.
Second, your "SELECT" clause

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT.EVENTLOCATION AND EVENTLOCATION ="LONDON 02"
```

is wrong. The syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE YOUR_CONDITIONS
```

so maybe something like this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,
CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
FROM CUSTOMER
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKING
ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM EVENT WHERE EVENTLOCATION="LONDON 02") AS LONDON_EVEN
ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
INNER JOIN CONCERTS
ON CONCERTS.CONCERTID=EVENT.CONCERTID
WHERE EVENT.EVENTID IS NULL;
```